# How do you move objects by dragging on the background in html5/canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to be able to create a movable canvas by dragging it, but being able to place objects onto the canvas that will stay in place relative to where they were placed. How would I go about doing that?

For example, I place 4 images in different places onto the canvas. Then I drag on an empty space on the canvas and all the objects move based on the movement of the mouse. Creating an illusion that the canvas has infinite space (because I would like to be able to place several objects beyond what the screen is showing).

Would I have to keep track of the objects themselves, and when I drag an empty space, make all the objects move? How will this affect memory if I had say a couple hundred of said objects onto the canvas (being out of view but being able to be brought back into view using this dragging method)?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that I translate the canvas context relative to the mouse movement. Please read the comments in the code.

In this example I'm drawing some circles. You can draw anything else.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
  cy = ch / 2;

//the mouse
let m = {x:0,y:0};//mouse coords on mouse down
let last_m = {x:0,y:0}//mouse coords on dragging
//distance
let d = {x:0,y:0};// distance while dragging
let D = {x:0,y:0};// distance on mouse up




// draw some circles
let circles = [];
let dragging = false;

function drawCircle(color){
  let o = {}
  o.x = (1 - Math.random() )* 3 * cw;
  o.y = Math.random() * ch;
  o.r = (Math.random() * 20) + 10;
  o.color = color;
  o.draw = function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = o.color;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(o.x,o.y,o.r,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }
  circles.push(o)
}


for(let i = 0; i < 70; i++){
drawCircle(`hsl(${i * 12},80%,60%)`)
}

for(let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){circles[i].draw()}


//events
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",(evt)=>{
  dragging = true;
  //the mouse position
  m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
})

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",(evt)=>{
  dragging = false;
  last_m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
  d.x = last_m.x - m.x;
  d.y = last_m.y - m.y;
  // the total dragged distance on mouse up
  D.x += d.x;
  D.y += d.y;
})


canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",(evt)=>{
  
  if(dragging){
    
    last_m = oMousePos(canvas, evt);
    
    d.x = last_m.x - m.x + D.x;
    d.y = last_m.y - m.y + D.y;
    
    // clear the context
    ctx.clearRect(-cw,0, 2*cw,ch);
    
    ctx.save();
    
    //translate the context
    ctx.translate(d.x, d.y);
    //repaint everithing
    for(let i = 0; i < circles.length; i++){circles[i].draw()}
    
    ctx.restore()
  }
                              
})


// a function to detect the mouse position on the canvas
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return { //objeto
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```